# Changing the Diagram Layout from down to up in Enterprise Architect via C# API

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

How can I change the layout direction of a diagram in Enterprise Architect via C# to get the same result as displayed in the picture:

[image: Setting the direction of a layout via EA GUI]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `t_diagram.StyleEx` so it contains `d=<n>;` where `<n>` is

> Up = 0, Down = 1, Left = 2, Right = 3

(see also my [Inside EA](http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html) book in p. 61)